# Murphy C* Algebra Chapter 1 Problem 13

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

A derivation on an algebra $A$ is a linear map $d: A \to A$ such that $d(ab) = ad(b)+d(a)b$ for all $a,b \in A$. Suppose $d$ is a bounded derivation on a unital Banach algebra $A$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is such that $d(a) = \lambda a$. Show that $a^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$.

The book gives a hint to use the boundedness of $\sigma(d)$, but I think the solution is quite easy. Induction gives $d(a^{2^k}) = 2^k\lambda a^{2^k}$ which means $2^k |\lambda| ||a^{2^k}|| \le ||d||\cdot ||a^{2^k}||$ so since $||d|| < \infty$, we clearly must have $a^{2^k} = 0$ for some $k$. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right, maybe the follwing is what the hint wants to hint you:

if $a$ is not a nilpotent, $d(a^{2^k})=2^k\lambda a^{2^k}\Rightarrow 2^k\lambda\in \sigma(d) ~ \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$, a contradiction to the boundedness of 
$\sigma(d)$.

By the way you can in fact verify $d(a^n)=n\lambda a^n$ by induction.